# Illuminate/Eloquent: how to use belongsTo in constructor

Tags: constructor, eloquent, belongs-to

i would like to provide data from the "foreign key table" in the current model.

I am currently achieving this by a function (getBrand).

But now I would like to have this accessable as a property. So I added a property ($brand) and wanted to fill it by calling the function (getBrand) in the constructor of the model.

```
class Car extends Eloquent {
  public $brand;

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->brand = getBrand();
  }

  public function getBrand() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand', 'FK_BrandId')->first()->Brandname;
  }
}
```

But this creates an error during the execution of the constructor:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change your `getBrand` function a little to the following to define the [relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) between a `Car` and a `Brand`:

```
 public function brand() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Brand', 'FK_BrandId');
 }
```

The brand model can then be accessed from an instance of `Car` with, e.g. `$car->brand`. To access the brand name you can then use `$car->brand->Brandname`.

If you'd like to access the brand name directly, you could define an ["accessor"](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on the `Car` model like this:

```
public function getBrandNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->brand->BrandName;
}
```

You would then be able to access the brand name with `$car->brand_name`.